# IIS - Remove trailing slash when directory

Tags: html, redirect, iis, web-config

I want to remove trailing slashes from all requests from "/" to "", even when it's a directory. For instance:

- Folder: *http://bleh.local/sign-in/*
- File to be served: *http://bleh.local/sign-in/index.html*
- Default document: *index.html*

I would like to redirect it to "http://bleh.local/sign-in"

- Expected behavior: */sign-in/* redirected to */sign-in*
- Actual behavior: */sign-in* redirected to */sign-in/*

Web.config:

```
<rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

applicationHost.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="rewrite">
    <section name="globalRules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" allowDefinition="AppHostOnly" />
    <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="outboundRules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="providers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="allowedServerVariables" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
</sectionGroup>
```

With this setup, I get infinite redirects because I removed this instruction from the original setup:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

I think my problems come from this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/298408/iis-generates-courtesy-redirect-when-folder-without-trailing-slash-is

Any ideas?

Note: [How can I configure IIS to serve directories without trailing slashes and always serve relative to root path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274704/how-can-i-configure-iis-to-serve-directories-without-trailing-slashes-and-always?rq=1) is not solving my problem. The backslashes are added consistently.

Comment: Into the same problem from 1 day . Unfortunately there's not any help over internet.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `<defaultDocument>` in IIS.

`<defaultDocument>` rule is enabled in IIS by default which forces the page to be redirected to the url with trailing slash, if it did not find a file. `domain/sign-in/`

```
<rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Now this rule, matches the url with the trailing slash (and matches directory) and in turn redirects to the one without the trailing slash. `domain/sign-in` which creates a loop.

The solution is to add the rule`<defaultDocument enabled="false"></defaultDocument>`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/defaultdocument/